# get list of application which have internet permission in android

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to list of application which have internet access permission. 
I have this example

```
PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager(); 
final List<PackageInfo> apps = p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
for (PackageInfo pkg : apps) {
for (String permission : pkg.requestedPermissions) {
    // Check if permission is the internet permission
}
}
```

but i am not getting this, how this code will check for internet permission?

can someone give full example???

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example fills `packageNames` with all the package name of the apps that require the internet permission:

```
ArrayList<String> packageNames = new ArrayList<String>();

PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
final List<PackageInfo> apps = p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
for (PackageInfo packageInfo : apps) {

    if (packageInfo.requestedPermissions == null)
        continue;

    for (String permission : packageInfo.requestedPermissions) {

        if (TextUtils.equals(permission, android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET)) {
            packageNames.add(packageInfo.packageName);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> how this code will check for internet permission?

By checking `permission` to see if it is the desired value:

```
PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager(); 
final List<PackageInfo> apps = p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

for (PackageInfo pkg : apps) {
    for (String permission : pkg.requestedPermissions) {
        if (Manifest.permission.INTERNET.equals(permission)) {
            // do something
            break;
        }
    }
}
```